# Need to reference/access Yup.ref() value within the message of yup min and max validations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have the following Yup validation and unsure how to reference the Yup.ref(a) value within the message of that `.min()` and `.max()`, i.e.:

```
  checkPercent: Yup.number()
    .when("summaryFlag", {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.number()
        .typeError('Value must be a number')
        .required('Value is required')
        .positive()
        .min(Yup.ref("percentLower"), `{The value must be > xx`)
        .max(Yup.ref("percentUpper"), `{The value must be < yy`)
  })
```

Using the above, how can I replace `xx` in my .min message with the actual value of `Yup.ref("percentLower")` ?

The same for `yy` to be replaced with the value of `Yup.ref("percentUpper")` ?

I tried using template literals syntax but it didn't work, i.e.:

`.min(Yup.ref("percentLower"), {The value must be > ${Yup.ref("percentLower")})`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function as the second argument to the `min` function. This function receives the actual value of the `percentLower` field.

```js
.min(
  Yup.ref("percentLower"),
  ({ min }) => `The value must be > ${min}`
)
```

Ref: [Yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringminlimit-number--ref-message-string--function-schema)